# Currency Format with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I know that it's been answered before and here's the code for it (Knockout JS)

```
ko.observable.fn.withCurrencyFormat = function (precision) {
    var observable = this;
    observable.formatted = ko.computed({
        read: function (key) {
            return '$' + (+observable()).toFixed(precision);
        },
        write: function (value) {
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            observable(isNaN(value) ? null : value); // Write to underlying storage 
        }
    });

    return observable;
};
```

But how can I handle these scenarios?

1. User deletes the 0.00 in the text field, it should default back
   to 0.00 instead of staying blank
2. User types letters in the text
   field, it should also default back to 0.00 instead of returning NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `read` function, which generates the output, the `NaN` is created here:

```
+observable() // The + tries to "cast" the observable's value to a number
```

To get rid of the `NaN`, you'll have to do an `isNaN` check:

```
var nr = +observable();
if (isNaN(nr)) {
  nr = 0;
}
```

Now, in your `write` method, which transforms the input, there's a `null` value returned for invalid input. Replace this to `0` to default to `$0.00`:

```
observable(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
```

If you can be sure the `formatted` computed is the only one writing to the underlying observable, you only need to fix one of these (i.e. you decide to format values on inputting them to the system or on outputting them).

The snippet below shows these fixes linked to an input. Personally, I think this behavior is better suited for an [extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html), but I'm not sure if it matters.

```js
ko.observable.fn.withCurrencyFormat = function (precision) {
    var observable = this;
    observable.formatted = ko.computed({
        read: function (key) {
          var nr = +observable();
          if (isNaN(nr)) nr = 0;
          
          return '$' + nr.toFixed(precision);
        },
        write: function (value) {
        
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            observable(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
        }
    }).extend({notify: 'always'});

    return observable;
};

var obs = ko.observable(0).extend({notify: 'always'});
var val = obs.withCurrencyFormat(2).formatted;

ko.applyBindings({
  val: val
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: val">
```