# How to correctly format currency with Knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, currency-formatting

I need to format number as localized currency with Knockoutjs. But I have issues with it. I created a jsfiddle for it. If somebody could be so nice, and check it (not fix it), please write it to me, what should I fix in it.

Example is here:

```js
ko.extenders.formattedMoney = function (target, arg) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
          var targetValue = target().toString().replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '');
          return parseInt(targetValue).toLocaleString('hu-HU') + " HUF";
        },
        write: target
    });

    result.raw = target;
    return result;
};

function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.minValue = ko.observable(20000);
  self.curValue = ko.observable(40000).extend({ formattedMoney: 0 });
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  MinValue: <input type="text" data-bind="value: minValue" />
</div>
<div>
  CurValue: <input type="text" data-bind="value: curValue" />
</div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: *"But I have issues with it"* What issues?

Comment: [There is a working solution in Stackoverflow itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546794/currency-format-with-knockout), Just refer that. Else just let us know the issue that you face. :)

Comment: When I change the number, but not deleted, just rewrite one character for example 40 000 Ft rewrite to 40 400 Ft then 40 Ft will be the result.

Comment: Ah, finally my example snippet is working. That regexp replace do the trick :)

Comment: Oh, next issue: my observable has a value: 40 000 HUF now, instead of 40000. How can I get easily the real number value of the observable?